# Show $|v^T (A \odot T) u| \le \|T\|_{max}|v^TAu|$, where $T_{ij}\in (0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Define $\|T\|_{max} = max_{i,j}|T_{ij}|\in(1,\infty)$, and $\odot$ is the element-wise product between two matrices.

I started with a simple example: $v = (v_1, v_2)^T$, $A_{ij} = a_{ij}$, where $i=1,2$ and $j = 1,2$, and $u = (u_1, u_2)^T$.

Then $|v^T (A \odot T) u| = | t_{11} a_{11}v_1u_1 + t_{12} a_{12}v_1u_2+ t_{21}a_{21}v_2u_1+t_{22}a_{22}v_2u_2 |$.

On the other hand, the right hand side is $$\left| \|T\|_{max}a_{11}v_1u_1 + \|T\|_{max}a_{12}v_1u_2+ \|T\|_{max}a_{21}v_2u_1+\|T\|_{max}a_{22}v_2u_2 \right|.$$

I don't see this inequality holds in general - what if some summand is negative?

I had this question when I was reading page 4 of this [material](https://dx.doi.org/10.1214/12-AOS1018SUPP). There the matrix $A$ is $\frac{Z^T Z}{n}-\Sigma_Z$, where $Z$ is a random design matrix, and each row $Z_i$ is (independent) sub-Gaussian random variable, and $\Sigma_Z$ is the population covariance matrix; moreover, there the vector $v=u\in \mathbb{R}^{p}$.

Please note the paper use element wise division, but for simplicity I changed my problem statement here to be element wise product. For example $M_{ij} = m_{ij}$ in the paper is $T_{ij} = t_{ij} = \frac{1}{m_{ij}}$. Moreover, we are given $m_{ij}\in(0,1)$ and $M$ is symmetric, therefore $t_{ij}\in(1,\infty)$ and $T$ is symmetric as well.

My question is:

1. In the specific case $A = \frac{Z^T Z}{n}-\Sigma_Z$, and $u=v$, how does the inequality hold?
2. Does the inequality hold in general, as described in the beginning? If not, what is the required condition?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation. Is $\odot$ Hadamard product? And is it taken on the matrices only?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes to all questions. I have edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: @Mittens There may be some misunderstanding. I use $\odot$ for element wise product between two matrices.

Comment: @maskeran: In your earlier posting you called it the Kronecker product. I see now that you have edited your question...

Comment: Actually, I just checked the paper: there they use elem. wise division with the matrix $M$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you for checking the paper! I originally used their notation (division), but to make it clear to the first time reader, I change it to element wise product, given there will be no major difference since all entries of $M$ are strictly between 0 and 1.

Comment: If the matrix $M$ that they are dividing by has entries in $(0,1)$, then your matrix $M$ here has entries in $(1, \infty)$ since they are reciprocals. Can you please make sure that you include *all* information? It's really annoying when someone has to dig through papers just to give a coherent answer. It is expected of you to do this.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you so much for catching that inconsistent statement. I realized it is very unclear and apologize for that. Yes since $M_{ij}\in(0,1)$ in the paper, when I change to the product, I should have mentioned $T_{ij}\in (1,\infty)$. That is completely my mistake. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: It turns out that there is more information that you have omitted to answer your questions, such as $Z = X \odot U$ where $u_{ij}$ is a Bernoulli variable. Supposedly this is a "missing-data" model.

Comment: @V.S.e.H.Thank you for mentioning that. I did intentionally not mention that because I understood $Z$ is sub-Guassian, and the problem can be framed directly using $Z$. For sure my judgement on what should to be included in my post or not need improvement. But for this particular question, I don't think including $Z=X\odot U$ is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question boils down to: for any two real vectors $x,y$, prove
$$
|x^Ty|\leq\|x\|_\infty|\mathbf{1}^Ty|,
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones.
Concretely in OP's case, we set $\DeclareMathOperator{\vec}{vec}x=\vec(M)$ and $y=\vec(A\odot vu^T).$
A simple counter example of this inequality would be $x=y=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}^T.$ However, if $y$ is nonnegative, then the inequality obviously holds via triangle inequality. That hopefully answers question 2.

As for 1, I think we need additional information about the matrices and vector. What is given is not enough. It can still be the case that the LHS is nonzero, and the RHS is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the original material I cited, $Z$ is sub-Gaussian matrix. I did not mentioned that because I thought it has little to do with their inequality. Besides that, both $Z^TZ$ and $\Sigma_Z$ are symmetric matrices. Given that, do you have any insight on how they derive their inequality on the top of page 4?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the entries of $M$ are in between $0$ and $1$.